# How to change specific places in data frame with respect to given formula

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's consider some random data with NA's filled with.

```
df1=data.frame(sample(0:1,3,replace=T),sample(0:1,3,replace=T),sample(0:1,3,replace=T))
df2=data.frame(rnorm(3),runif(3),rexp(3))
df2[df1==1]<-NA
df2
      rnorm.3.  runif.3.  rexp.3.
1        NA        NA       NA
2 0.6992316        NA 0.638913
3 0.6520083 0.1090714       NA
```

I want to replace those NA's with formula : 2*sd(x) + mean(x)

where sd is standard deviation. I want to do it of course with respect to proper columns so the NA in 1 row and 1 column should be replace by formula : 2*sd(0.6992316,0.6520083)+mean(0.6992316,0.6520083) and so on.

I tried to do it by the code : `df2[df2==NA]<-2*apply(df2,2,sd,na.rm=T)+apply(df2,2,mean,na.rm=T)` but nothing happened. Do you have idea how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably write the (vectorized) function using `ifelse` then apply to all the columns using `mutate(across(everything()))`

```r
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x)  ifelse(!is.na(x), x,
                         2 * sd(x, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), f))
#>    rnorm.3.  runif.3.  rexp.3.
#> 1 0.7424038        NA       NA
#> 2 0.6992316        NA 0.638913
#> 3 0.6520083 0.1090714       NA
```

Note that in your example this doesn't do anything for the second two columns because they only have a single non-NA value. Calling `sd` on a single non-NA value produces `NA`.

If however, we do it with only one `NA` in each column (as we get by re-running your code after setting `set.seed(1)`), we can see this working:

```
set.seed(1)
df1  <- data.frame(sample(0:1, 3, replace = TRUE),
                   sample(0:1, 3, replace = TRUE),
                   sample(0:1, 3, replace = TRUE))
df2  <- data.frame(rnorm(3), runif(3), rexp(3))
df2[df1 == 1] <- NA
df2

#>     rnorm.3.  runif.3.   rexp.3.
#> 1 -1.5399500 0.4976992 1.2132879
#> 2         NA        NA 0.5548904
#> 3 -0.2947204 0.9919061        NA

df2 %>% mutate(across(everything(), f))
#>     rnorm.3.  runif.3.   rexp.3.
#> 1 -1.5399500 0.4976992 1.2132879
#> 2  0.8436853 1.4437167 0.5548904
#> 3 -0.2947204 0.9919061 1.8152038
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? The second column has NA still because there is only 1 non-NA value, standard deviation of a single value is NA, adding mean or any value to NA is also NA, hence it's not getting imputed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(., 2*sd(., na.rm = T) + mean(., na.rm = T))))
    rnorm.3.  runif.3.    rexp.3.
1 -0.3030444        NA 0.07332792
2 -0.2226609        NA 1.76854904
3 -0.3909707 0.9099274 0.95892457
>
```